# amazon and adsense referer urls

Tags: adsense, article, affiliate, referer

I want to create a little website and I want to know some things about amazon affiliate and google adsense. Here is my questions that I want to know and couldn't find answers:

1) I have a website and there are few of us who post articles about some products, can I somehow find out from which url user bought a thing? for example if I will will create article `www.example.com/article1` and my friend `www.example.com/article2` about same thing and user will buy thing from article1, than will amazon show that user bought a  thing from `www.example.com/article1` not from `www.example.com/article2` ?

2) Is it possible to measure how much each articles earn with amazon affiliate or google adsense? for example will amazon or adsense show `www.example.com/article1` earned 5$ and `www.example.com/article2` 100$ ?

please give me the answers, I am realy stuck with this and can't find a way out. I don't want to register on amazon affiliate or adsense without knowing this things.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about ads / tracking rather than about programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Amazon: Use two separate tracking ids in each of the articles.
Adsense: You can set up custom channels for each author and get separate ad codes that way.

Comment: can I do both of those programely with php script? on 1-st case I can't manually use separate tracking ids for each articles, the articles will be too many for that, so can I do that with script? and what about adsense: how many custom channels can I create? what is the maximum number?